# Get value of a custom attribute in Java Code

Tags: android

I create an attribute in attrs.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="Custom">
        <attr name="src" format="integer" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resource>
```

And in my code, I get the value of the attribute like this:
attrs.getAttributeIntValue("mynamespace", "src", -1);

It works. I get the value of 'src' from the layout xml file.
But my question is why android does not generate a value in R class so that I don't need to use the string 'src' again in my java code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead use the [`TypedArray`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/TypedArray.html)

```
public CustomView(final Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public CustomView(final Context context,
            final AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public CustomView(final Context context,
            final AttributeSet attrs, final int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    final TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
                R.styleable.Custom, defStyle, 0);

    int src = a.getInt(R.styleable.Custom_src, 0);

    a.recycle();
}
```